# Struts2 validation bypass/block, table pagination

Tags: struts2

I have two action classes, UserAction(methods: login, logout) & EmployeeAction(methods: add, update, view) both have a validate method. It is invoked for every method by default. Is there a way to bypass call to validate method on say logout, as doing so throws an nullpointer exception on fields. Same for view method, that doesn't need any validation.

struts.xml

```
<action name="*Employee" method="{1}" class="package.EmployeeAction">
    <result name="not_found">/WEB-INF/errors/not_found.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/{1}Employee.jsp</result>
</action>
```

2) how can I implement client side validation for 3 jsp pages, add.jsp, view.jsp & update.jsp which all call a method of a single action class?
3) are there any tutorials on how to create table pagination in struts2? I was unable to locate one. documentation?
-Nishant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass validation for specific method names by adding them to the `excludeMethods` parameter of the [validation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation-interceptor.html) and [workflow](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/workflow-interceptor.html) interceptors.  If you look at the defaultStack definition, you'll see it's already excluding a few common method names.  Just add **logout** to the list:

```
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
              <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,logout</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,logout</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
how can I implement client side validation for 3 jsp pages, add.jsp, view.jsp & update.jsp which all call a method of a single action class?
```

All you need to do is set `validate = true` in form tag in you JSP. You can refer this [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ajax-validation.html)

```
are there any tutorials on how to create table pagination in struts2?
```

You can try [display tags](http://displaytag.sf.net). This tag library have good support for pagination.

Hope this helps